# How to unit test withLatestFrom in ngrx effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, jasmine-marbles

I have an effect that is taking the latest from params and passing that into an exhaustMap that then calls a service.

```
@Effect()
loadPlansOnParams$ = this.actions$.pipe(
 ofType(backlogActions.BacklogActionTypes.GET_BOARDS_IN_PARAMS),
 withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromRoot.getRouterState), (action, router) => {
   const {
     state: {
       queryParams: { boards },
     },
   } = router;
   return {
     boards,
   };
 }),
 exhaustMap(payload => {
   return this.boardService.getBoardsFromParams(payload.boards).pipe(
     map((res: SignalRResult) => {
       const board = res.item;
       return new backlogActions.GetBoardsSuccess(board);
     }),
     catchError(err => of(new backlogActions.GetBoardsError(err))),
   );
 }),
);
```

Everything is cool. However I cannot get this to test for the life of me. And just about every example I can find is useless.

Here is My test...

```
describe('getting boards from the params', () => {
    it('should return an empty array if no params', () => {
      const params = { state: { queryParams: {} } };
      const successfulSignalRResult = { isSuccessful: true, item: [] };
      const action = new backlogActions.GetBoardsInParams();
      const outcome = new backlogActions.GetAvailableBoardsSuccess([]);
      actions.stream = hot('-a', { a: action });
      store.select = jest.fn(() => of(params));
      expected = cold('--b', { b: outcome });
      boardSvc.getBoardsFromParams = jest.fn(() => successfulSignalRResult);
      expect(effects.loadPlansOnParams$).toBeObservable({});
    });
  });
```

No matter what I do with the store.select mock I get back "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected."

Any help is appreciated. I'm really hoping that I'm missing something on marbles.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? I encountered the exact same problem

Comment: Nope. Just left it untested.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same issue and for me the fix was to provide a mock for selectors that are inside the withLatestFrom operator. like this :

```
provideMockStore({
      initialState: fromStore.initialState,
      selectors: [
        {
          selector: fromStore.getCriteriaList,
          value: {
            industries: '',
            keyword: '',
            tags: ''
          }
        }
      ]
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this is late answer. I have encountered same problem.

I don't know the exact reason. In my thought, getRouterState is not initialized when MockStore and effect are used at the same time. When loadPlansOnParams$ is initialized in constructor, getRouterState is not properly initialized.

Simply speaking, initialization for getRouterState is located before loadPlansOnParams$ like this.

```
@Effect()

SomeVariableForGetRouterState:Observable<SomeThing> = ..... fromRoot.getRouterState ..... like this.. 

loadPlansOnParams$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(backlogActions.BacklogActionTypes.GET_BOARDS_IN_PARAMS),
withLatestFrom( SomeVariableForGetRouterState, (action, router) => {
.....
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but I was having a similar problem. I believe you have to initialize the store with the correct router data.
Many thanks to [this excellent youtube video by @brian_love](https://youtu.be/AYBHKoiozhg) and his [github repo](https://github.com/blove/ngrx-testing.git)

Things to note:

- I'm using provideMockStore and provideMockActions
- I'm initializing the TestBed and providing my mock implementations

Here's my working example:

```js
import { cold, hot } from 'jasmine-marbles'
import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import * as fromStore from '.';
import { ApplicationDocument } from 'shared-libs';
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { ApplicationDocumentService } from '../application-document.service';
import { ApplicationDocumentEffects } from './application-document.effects';

describe('ApplicationDocument Store', () => {

  let applicationDocument: ApplicationDocument
  let error: any
  let actions$: Actions
  let service: ApplicationDocumentService
  let effects: ApplicationDocumentEffects
  let store: any
  
  describe('effects', () => {
  // Note: Must initialize store with router state
    const initialState = {
      router: {
        state: { params: { applicationId: 1 } }
      }
    }
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          ApplicationDocumentEffects,
          provideMockStore({ initialState }), //<-- must provide the initialState to the mockStore
          provideMockActions(() => actions$),
          {
            provide: ApplicationDocumentService,
            useValue: {
              getDocuments: jest.fn()
            }
          }
        ]
      })

      effects = TestBed.inject(ApplicationDocumentEffects)
      service = TestBed.inject(ApplicationDocumentService)
      store = TestBed.inject(MockStore)
    })
    
    
    it('should be created', () => {
      expect(effects).toBeTruthy();
    });
    
    describe('loadDocuments', () => {

      it('should return loadApplicationDocumentsSuccess action, with the documents', () => {
        applicationDocument = {documentId: 1};

        const action = fromStore.loadApplicationDocuments();
        const outcome = fromStore.loadApplicationDocumentsSuccess({ 
          applicationDocuments: [applicationDocument] 
        })
        actions$ = hot('-a', { a: action })

        const response = cold('-a|', { a: [applicationDocument] })
        const expected = cold('--b', { b: outcome })
        service.getDocuments = jest.fn(() => response)

        expect(effects.loadApplicationDocuments$).toBeObservable(expected)
      })
    })

  })
  
  });
```